# Why XSLT Round(3241.44 * 3 ) div 3 is 3241.3333333333335

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

Why XSLT Round(3241.44 * 3 ) div 3 is 3241.3333333333335

I am expecting 3241.44 after the formula : Round(3241.44 * 3 ) div 3

Please explain the inner working of round and div keywords.
Generally round is used with div 100/10000/100000 etc., Why do we use multiples of 10s

Comment: In XPath 1.0, as in JavaScript, number are IEEE doubles, so the result you see is simply the defined result of the underlying floating point operation.

Comment: "Please explain the inner working" Do you want the 10-page explanation or the 100-page explanation? Floating point arithmetic is not easy to explain in one sentence, and there's plenty of reading material available.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting 3241.44 after the formula : Round(3241.44 * 3 ) div 3

First, the  result you expect makes no sense.

```
3241.44 * 3 = 9724.32  
round (9724.32) = 9724  
9724 / 3 = 3241 ⅓
```

Now, how the fraction of one third is represented as a decimal number depends on your processor. For example, `libxslt` will return:

```
3241.33333333333
```

which is the correct result rounded to 11 decimal places. Other processors (notably those based on Java, such as Xalan and Saxon) will return:

```
3241.3333333333335
```

which is the result of a [roundoff error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

Note that the [XPath 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#numbers) states:

> A number represents a floating-point number.
> …
> The `div` operator performs floating-point division according to IEEE 754.

For the "inner workings" of the algorithm, you may want to read this tutorial: https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/floating-point-tutorial.html.

---

Note also that your formula:

```
Round(3241.44 * 3 ) div 3
```

will produce an error and not the result you claim. XML is case-sensitive and the function is `round()`, not `Round()`.